# AWS lambda node.js

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, lambda

I have problem with saving data to DynamoDB from Lambda function writted in node.js. I would like to ask if i have my code written good, cause i will need to save about 100 items every second and i cannot find other way to save data to DynamoDB from Lambda function instead of put function. When i try to save about 500 items(500 records) it makes task timeout delay. If i save about 50 items, it sometimes save all data but sometimes there are about 20 items and sometimes it doesnt save anything. My lambda code:

```
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");
var dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

var numberOfInsertedRows = 0;  
var actualInsertedRow = 0;

var insertItem = function(oneRow, context){
    var params = {};
    params.TableName = 'MyTable';
    params.Item = oneRow;

    dynamodb.put(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('ERROR');
            console.log(err);
            context.fail('some error');
        }
        else {
            actualInsertedRow++;
            if(actualInsertedRow == numberOfInsertedRows){
                console.log('All items saved');
                context.succeed('ok');
            }
        }
    });
};

exports.handler = function(event, context) {
    numberOfInsertedRows = event.length;
    actualInsertedRow = 0;

    event.forEach(function(item){
         insertItem(item, context);
    });
};
```

update: now i use batchWriteItem which is limited to 25 records in one batch so i can use it in for-each and when i have 25 items i send them in batch...but still have problem with big duration (putItem was about 4000 ms and batch is about 3500 ms, which is very bad for only insert about 100 records). My clientApp cannot wait so long for responses. What could be problem?

Comment: Why can't your client wait 3-4 seconds? I'm not saying it should be taking that long, but that seems like an unreasonably low timeout restriction. I would try creating an array of batches, and running several batches in parallel. Also, what is the provisioned write capacity of the table you are inserting into?

Comment: Provisioned write capacity is set to 5. I try to set it on 10 but durations were the same. Operations, parsing nad calculations inside lambda are done in about 200ms, but when i want to save one batch(25 records) into DynamoDB, it started to raise near 1000ms and when i try to put f.e. 4 batches, the duration value will be about 5000ms. Maybe i am wrong in code, but i need very low delay for client, cause there will be very big traffic. I can send you my code with using batchWriteItem or post it here.

Comment: So you're trying to write hundreds of items a second, but only provisioned your table to handle 10 per second. I'm guessing you are being throttled by DynamoDB. Try logging the ConsumedCapacity metrics returned from the DynamoDB API calls to see what is going on.